# Split address and numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to split street name, house number, and box number from a String.
Let's say the string is *"**SomeStreet 59A**"*
For this case I already have a solution with regex. I'm using this function:

```
address.split(/([0-9]+)/) //output ["SomeStreet","59","A"]
```

The **problem** I'm having now, is that some addresses have weird formats. Meaning, the above method does not fit for strings like:

```
"Somestreet 59-65" // output ["SomeStreet", "59", "-", "65"] Not good
```

My question for this case is, how to group the numbers to get this **desired output**:

```
["Somestreet", "59-65"]
```

**Another weird example is:**

```
"6' SomeStreet 59" // here "6' Somestreet" is the exact street-name.
```

Expected output: `["6' Somestreet", "59"]`

```
"6' Somestreet 324/326 A/1" // Example with box number
```

Expected output: `["6' Somestreet", "324/326", "A/1"]`

Bear in mind that this has to be in one executable function to loop through all of the addresses that I have.

Comment: There are so many different forms of street addresses, trying to come up with a simple function to parse them is futile.

Comment: Try `.split(/\s*(\d+(?!['’\d])(?:-\d+)?)/)` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/QOGXUX/1/)) if all acceptable formats are those you listed in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To support all string formats listed in the question, you can use

```js
.match(/^(.*?)\s+(\d+(?:[-.\/]\d+)?)(?:\s*(\S.*))?$/)
.match(/^(.*)\s+(\d+(?:[-.\/]\d+)?)(?:\s*(\S.*))?$/)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QOGXUX/4).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible (if you need to match the last number as Group 2, the `Number`, you need to use `.*`, a greedy variant)
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(\d+(?:[-.\/]\d+)?)` - Group 2: one or more digits optionally followed with `-`/`.`/`/` and then one or more digits
- `(?:\s*(\S.*))?` - an optional occurrence of zero or more whitespaces and - Group 3 - a non-whitespace char and the rest of the string
- `$` - end of string.

See a JavaScript demo:

```js
const texts = ['SomeStreet 59A','Somestreet 59-65',"6' SomeStreet 59", 'Somestreet 1.1', 'Somestreet 65 A/1', "6' Somestreet 324/326 A/1"];
const rx = /^(.*?)\s+(\d+(?:[-.\/]\d+)?)(?:\s*(\S.*))?$/;
for (const text of texts) {
  const [_, street, number, box] = text.match(rx);
  console.log(text, '=>', {"Street":street, "Number":number, "Box":box});
}
```

Comment: Thanks! one more problem i'm having is with "Somestreet 1.1" I've tried doing the following with your code: ```\s*(\d+(?!['\d])(?:-\d+)?)(?:.\d)?``` but the output of the number is 1 instead of 1.1

Comment: @Yorbjörn No, it should be `/\s*(\d+(?!['’\d])(?:[-.]\d+)?)/;` where `[-.]` stands for a hyphen or dot.

Comment: Okay so one last time i'm bothering you ^^, 
I have a case like this:
```"Somestreet 65 A/1" // output  --> ["Somestreet", "65", "A/"]```

Comment: @Yorbjörn This is no longer clear. Do you want to remove the final number? Or a number after `/` at the end of string? Try `/\s*(?:(?<=\/)\d+$|(\d+(?!['’\d])(?:[-.]\d+)?))/`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/QOGXUX/2).

Comment: I'd like to keep the "1" after the "A/" because in this case it is part of the boxnumber

Comment: @Yorbjörn It is not clear from your comment. Try `/\s*(?<!\/)(\d+(?!['’\d])(?:[-.]\d+)?)/`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/QOGXUX/3).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230536/discussion-between-yorbjorn-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Comment: Why are there 2 regexes? Which one should we use?

Comment: @JimmyKane It depends on what kind of input you have, cf. [the lazy version](https://regex101.com/r/QOGXUX/7) with the [greedy one](https://regex101.com/r/QOGXUX/8).

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind a bit of string trimming afterwards, here's a solution:

```js
.split(/(?= \d|\D+$)/)
```

or to account also for `65 A/1` or `324/326 A/1`

```
.split(/(?= \d|\D+$|(?<!\D) )/)
```

[Regex101.com demo](https://regex101.com/r/eZlNKN/2)

```js
[
  "Some Street 59A",
  "Some Street 59-69",
  "Some Street 1.1",
  "6' Street 45b",
  "6' Some street 324/326 A/1",
  "Some Street 65 A/1",
  "42th Stack ave. 59-69",
].forEach(str => console.log( str.split(/(?= \d|\D+$|(?<!\D) )/) ));
```

If you want to keep the *number* i.e: `59A` as a whole, here's another simple solution:

```js
.split(/(?= \d| [\w\d/]+$)/);
```

[Regex101.com demo](https://regex101.com/r/eZlNKN/3)

```js
[
  "Some Street 59A",
  "Some Street 59-69",
  "Some Street 1.1",
  "6' Street 45b",
  "6' Some street 324/326 A/1",
  "Some Street 65 A/1",
  "42th Stack ave. 59-69",
].forEach(str => console.log( str.split(/(?= \d| [\w\d/]+$)/) ));
```